# Assembly compare one bit of register

Tags: assembly, x86, bare-metal, protected-mode

I need to compare one bit of register e.g. lets say `AH` is equal to 0b010010>1<0,
 and I need to check is 2nd bit (to make sure we are talking about the same bit I put this bit between arrows) is 1 or 0.

If this may help my code suppose to run on PMode 32 bit with no operation system.

I found on internet that this can be done with `test` instruction, but I didn't found way how to do it.

Comment: `test` is bitwise `and` operation (as the instruction set reference tells you). I hope you know how that works, if not, read about it. In short, you can do `test ah, 2`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra the test instruction as the documentation you should be reading.  a test is usually an and instruction but doesnt save the result only changes the flags.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know id this helps: Avr assembly has the commands sbrc and sbrs which basically check a single bit of a register (lsb is bit0) and skip the next command accordingly:

```
sbrc AH, 1    ;if bit1 of AH is 0, then skip the next instruction

sbrs AH, 1    ;if bit1 of AH is 1, then skip the next instruction
```

Comment: The x86 equivalent is `bt eax, 1+8` to set CF = bit#9 (the 2nd bit of AH), then `jc` or `jnc`.  But normally you'd `test ah, 1<<1` to set ZF according to `AH & mask == 0`.  This is an x86 question; AH is an x86 register name.  I'll fix the tags on the question.